# Get columns that correspond to when clause

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I want to create a column which contains columns that are equal to 0. Input:

```
+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|
+---+---+---+
|  0|  0|  4|
|  2|  1|  3|
| 56|  4|  3|
|  0|  5|  5|
+---+---+---+
```

Desired output

```
+---+---+---+----+
|  A|  B|  C| Err|
+---+---+---+----+
|  0|  0|  4| A;B|
|  2|  1|  3|null|
| 56|  4|  3|null|
|  0|  5|  5|  A;|
+---+---+---+----+
```

I tried this:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((0, 0, 4), (2, 1, 3), (56, 4, 3), (0, 5, 5))).toDF("A", "B", "C")

df.withColumn("Err", when(col("A")==="0", "A;").when(col("B")==="0", "B;").when(col("C")==="0", "C;"))
```

I got his:

```
+---+---+---+----+
|  A|  B|  C| Err|
+---+---+---+----+
|  0|  0|  4|  A;|
|  2|  1|  3|null|
| 56|  4|  3|null|
|  0|  5|  5|  A;|
+---+---+---+----+
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [concat_ws](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#concat_ws-java.lang.String-org.apache.spark.sql.Column...-) to achieve the desired output.

```scala
df.withColumn("Err", concat_ws(";", when(col("A")==="0", "A"), when(col("B")==="0", "B"), when(col("C")==="0", "C")))
```

```
+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|Err|
+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  0|  4|A;B|
|  2|  1|  3|   |
| 56|  4|  3|   |
|  0|  5|  5|  A|
+---+---+---+---+
```

It is then easy to transform the empty strings into `null` if you really need to.

If the number of columns that shouldn't be 0 is long, you can store the list in a variable and use `map`:

```scala
val columnsThatShouldNotBeZero = List("A", "B", "C")
df.withColumn("Err", concat_ws(";", columnsThatShouldNotBeZero.map(colName => when(col(colName) === "0", colName)): _*))
```